# loadBalancerSourceRanges not working for google kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed this service.yaml to my cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 123.123.123.123/32
```

`123.123.123.123/32` is my public IP address. But this service is not accessible from my public IP for some reason. This is supposed to be supported by GCP now.

If I use expose it works but opens up ALL traffic which I why I want to use loadBalancerSourceRanges

```
kubectl expose deployment mydeployment --type=LoadBalancer --port 8888 --target-port 8888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: morgua-api-loadbalancer
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges: "130.211.204.1/32, 173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22"
...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Now in GKE has Firewall. You need to accept your IP.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s YOUR_IP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s YOUR_IP -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: that is not what he is asking. his question relates to the capability to whitelist firewalls using 'loadBalancerSourceRanges' parameter.

Comment: Him loadBalancerSourceRanges is true. But GKE has Firewall, he need turn off Firewall to connect.

Comment: he states if he "If I use expose it works " vuia kubectl meaning its not a firewall issue.